# spring5 webflux, how to return custom json data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

when i don`t use webflux, my code

```
1.public Map<String, Object> registerService(User user) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(8);
    map.put("status":1);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return map;
```

when i used webflux, my code

```
2.public Mono<Map<String, Object>> registerService(User user) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(8);
    map.put("status", 1);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return Mono.just(map);
}
```

and 2. response is "{"status":1}",but user don`t insert mongo

### in webflux, i can`t get the same as 1. response, so  how to do it?

i don`t want to return User, just return i custom Map, and user insert into mongodb

Comment: so what does your userRepository.save() do?

Comment: insert user into mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your user repository return type is also a Mono, and you would like to return your custom map, you could do

```
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> registerService(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user)
        .map(__ -> {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("status", 1);
            return map;
        });
}
```

in the code above, you're not breaking the reactive chain, but you're returning your custom map like you wanted to.

Comment: hi friend, thank you very much.  i try to use your code,  but  when i  calling registerService(),  user is return null, i really don`t know what`s wrong....user={"username":"admin","password":"123456"}....mongodb return my user is null

Comment: request_data  : {"username":"admin","password":"123456"}     response: "Failed to instantiate [com.reactive.entity.User]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: username is marked @NonNull but is null"

Comment: @LceMan that's something different, not related to problem described in this question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to subscribe to the Mono, `userRepository.save(obj).subscribe()`.

Comment: public Mono<Map<String, Object>> registerService(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(8);
        map.put("status", 1);
        userRepository.save(user).subscribe();
        return Mono.just(map);
    }

Comment: subscribe()  notice   Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking scope less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Methods returning a Publisher type (Publisher, Flux, Mono) should not call the subscribe method directly because it can break the reactive call chain. Instead of using subscribe consider using composition operators like flatMap, zip, then, etc

Comment: i don`t want to return User, just return i custom Map, and user insert into mongodb